# JavaFX is there a way to include PDF files

Tags: java, pdf, javafx

Is there a way to include a PDF file to my JavaFX application? It doesn't have to open it up, only the file should be included

And is there a possibility to let the pdf reader, that is installed on the pc open it up?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with "included"?

Comment: When opening the application there should be a pdf icon, and optionally can be clicked to open the pdf file from the installed pdf reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like @Puce said, but do it the javafx way (not AWT)

```
yourApplication.getHostServices().showDocument(path);
```

Comment: I might be wrong (I haven't tested it), but is hostedServices not only available for JavaFX applets or maybe Java Web Start JavaFX applications?

Comment: No, it works for standalone applications too. Note however that `path` there should be a valid URL, i.e. you should have `File pdfFile = ... ;` and then `showDocument(pdfFile.toURI().toString());`

Comment: @James_D Thanks, good to know. Of course you meant Path (NIO.2 File API), not java.io.File ;-)

Comment: Either works, no? (Though with `java.nio.file.Path` the method would be `toUri()`, not `toURI()`.)

Answer (score 0):

> And is there a possibility to let the pdf reader, that is installed on
>   the pc open it up?

AFAIK, there is currently only the [Desktop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class from AWT, but you should be able to call this class from JavaFX as well.

Try (untested):

```
File pdfFile = ...;
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN)){
        desktop.open(pdfFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but the solution of @griFlo works better for me. I am still very grateful for your help!